# Dependency Scanning of Generated Source Code in SCons

Tags: dependencies, code-generation, scons, build-system

I have the following requirement for a build graph

`x.c` depends on `x.h` which depends on `y.h`, and `x.h` is generated from `x.xml` with a separate builder

in our SCons project as we want to start using generation of source code previously placed in the source directories.

However, this currently doesn't work as there seems to be no way to tell the scanner of `x.c` to first generate `x.h`.

Does SCons support scanning of dependencies in generated source code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like the Tool you have for building sources from x.xml doesn't let SCons know that it will be creating x.h.

Also note scanner's don't generate or cause tools to run, they just add info the the DAG which SCons then processes to build your software.

You should probably read:
https://bitbucket.org/scons/scons/wiki/ToolsForFools

The emitter for the tool which builds x.h from x.xml should indicate all the files it generates.